# Joining 2 layers by location doesn't join desired fields from attributes tables

Tags: qgis, shapefile, spatial-join

I have 2 layers that I'm trying to join by location: 1 is a point layer (CRS 4326) and the other is a shapefile layer (CRS 4326). The shapefile layer has a field in the attribute table whose values I want assigned to the points that fall within/along the boundaries of their respective shapes. (i.e. each point is a lat/lon coordinate, and the shapefile layer is a bunch of property parcels--some of which contain the points).

But when I join them by location the output layer doesn't include any of the fields from the shapefile layer. I just get new fields with sum, mean, max, min etc.

Is there a way to make this happen? I've tried this with QGIS 2.18 and QGIS3 without success.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE! Please take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and find out how to ask good questions. Specifically, please tell us the exact options that you have checked (a screenshot would be perfect!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are using "Join attributes by location (Summary)". Try "Join attributes by location" Since property parcels are probably not overlaping you can use one-to-one join type:

[image]

If this does not work my guess would be there is something wrong with data and I suggest you browse through Q/A on this topic: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=join+by+location.

Comment: Thanks Mat, selecting the "one-to-one" option when joining by location did the trick. I misunderstood what "take attributes of first located feature" meant and chose the "one-to-many" option on the first try.